# Криво открывается модальное окно bootstrap, Angular 2

Tags: bootstrap, angular2, typescript

Есть компонент модалки, через сервис для работы с модалками (экземпляр **NgbModal**) модальное окно открывается, но делает это криво (body не добавляется класс "**modal-open**").

Очень интересный факт, что при клике по странице (в любое место) модалка становится нормальной. Также, при закрытии модального окна должен происходить редирект в другое состояние, но этого не происходит, хотя замыкание срабатывает 100%.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Сам компонент модалки:

```
import {
 ChangeDetectionStrategy,
 Component,
 Input,
 OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: "example-selector",
  templateUrl: "./example.file.html",
  styleUrls: ["./example.file.sass"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class GlobalErrorComponent implements OnInit{
 @Input() error: any;
 constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }
 ngOnInit() {}
}
```

сервис, который осуществляет вызов модального окна:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CustomErrorComponent } from './custom.error.component';

@Injectable()

export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  private _modalRef: NgbModalRef | null = null;
  private get _router(): Router {
  return this._injector.get(Router);
}
private get _modalService(): NgbModal {
  return  this._injector.get(NgbModal);
}

constructor(private _injector: Injector) { }

handleError(error: any) {
  if (!this._modalRef) this._modalRef = this._modalService.open(CustomErrorComponent);
  this._modalRef.componentInstance.error = error;
  this._modalRef.result.then(res => {
    this._modalRef = null;
    console.log('it works');
    this._router.navigate(['state']);
  })
 }
}
```

Comment: .нужен [mcve] .

Comment: @Grundy , добавил код и уточнил детали

Answer (score 0):

если ты используешь `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, то грубо говоря все твои эвенты направлены "из" компонента (можешь проверить в`ngDoCheck`). Для решения вопроса тебе стоит убрать `changeDetection` или же добавить создание модалки в зону действия самого `changeDetection`. Для этого существует такой класс, как `ChangeDetectorRef` вот доки https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef